# what does "+" means in Objective-C files

Tags: objective-c, syntax, coding-style

I've been reading some Obj-C projects, and I'm always finding this standard for naming files:

```
ClassName+OtherClassName.h
```

What does this mean? Normally is used with a base class used on the left side, and another class used on the right side, like:

```
NSString+URLEncoding.h
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realized the second part of the filename _may not_ be another class name, so be careful with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I have seen it used is as a way of organizing *categories*, which are code extensions added to classes. Each category is given its own header and source file. The '+' is simply another character in the file name, though it is not often used. You can read more about categories [here](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's a naming convention, nothing more. In that case, it would be for a category on `NSString` that implements something to do with URL encoding.